# AWS EC2-Classic instances (PHP)

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

How to create an AWS EC2-Classic instance using AWS SDK for PHP API
I couldn't find any documentation on this particular topic.

Comment: If you created your AWS account after 2013-12-04, it does not support EC2-Classic, so you must launch your Amazon EC2 instances in a VPC.

Comment: I did not know that, thank you very much for your help

Comment: Is there a particular reason _why_ you would want an EC2 Classic instance?

Comment: i need to get new elastic IPs every time i restart the Ec2 instance, without having to do it with API ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EC2-Classic platform was introduced in the original release of Amazon EC2. If you created your AWS account after 2013-12-04, it does not support EC2-Classic, so you must launch your Amazon EC2 instances in a VPC.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-classic-platform.html

Also, In response to your comment " I need to get new elastic IPs every time i restart the Ec2 instance, without having to do it with API ... – "

Why do you need Elastic IP for this? If you want a new IP every-time you public IP instead. Every time the Instance stop/starts it will automatically get a new Public IP.

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/using-instance-addressing.html

Comment: I had instances with 1 public IP and 5 Elastic IPs, i needed all those IPs to be changed after restart.

Thanks for your response.

Comment: Now that, seems to be a problem because if you dissociate the Elastic IP, you Instance would not have public IP. You could probably create a AMI of all the Instances and launch instances from the AMI in the same subnet, so that they get public IP at launch.What did you do?

Comment: I did exactly that, although i noticed if i allocate and associate new IPs while the instance is stopped then my public IP would be one of those elastic IPs (after i start it), but if i start the instance then allocate and associate my IPs, then i would have a new public IP plus 5 unique Elastic IPs.